# Stop Typescript prettier to remove type in catch

Tags: typescript, prettier

TypeScript enforce specifing the type in `catch` to be `any`:

```
try {
...
}catch (e: any)
```

Otherwise, typescript will complain

> Object is of type 'unknown'

However, prettier will remove `any` when I run this:

```
prettier --write '**/*.{js,ts}'
```

How could it be stopped?

And interesting prettier doesn't remove `any` on `format on save`.

Comment: have you tried setting the type as `unknown`?

Comment: You should be using the `useUnknownInCatchVariables` compiler option.

Comment: @youdateme It stops the TS to complain but I am looking for an option to stop Prettier to complain.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible right now.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Did you find a solution?